# data migration in informatica

Tags: database, data-migration, informatica

A large amount of data is coming from source to target. After a successful insertion in target, we have to change the status to every rows as "committed". But when will we know that all datas have come or not in target without directly querying the source?

For example - suppose 10 records have migrated to target from source. 
We cannot change the status of all the records as "committed" before successful insertion of all records in target.

So before changing the status of all the records, how will we know that 11th record is coming or not? 
Is there anything that will give me the information about total records in source?

I need a real-time based answer.

Comment: please give me a good solution..

Comment: What is the source? Are we talking about a real-time session? Usually you could just use Post-SQL to execute update statement.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same scenario and this is what we did: 
First of all 
to check if data is loaded in target you can join source and target table, update will lock the rows so for this commit must be fired at database level in target table (so that lock for update can happen).

after joining, update the loaded data based on join with target column.

Few things.
You have to stop you session (used pmcmd to stop session in command task)
update data in your source table and restart session.

keep load for counter of 20k-30 rows so update goes smoothly.